# Каким образом можно объединить аутентификацию двух сайтов?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Каким образом можно объединить аутентификацию двух сайтов?

Есть два сайта (два проекта).

На одном проекте - стандартная аутентификация - индивидуальные учётные записи.

Второй проект должен автоматически аутентифицировать пользователя если он прошёл аутентификацию на первом.

Стандартная аутентификаця на основе куки. Но рассматриваю и другие варианты .

Как понимаю, как-то нужно получить куки и их проверять на другом проекте?

Comment: Это достаточно большой вопрос. Строится это не на базе кук, а на базе identity provider и токенов. Вы например видели вход на сайт через какой-нибудь вконтактик и слышали такие слова как OpenID и OAuth? Почитать можно тут: [single sign on](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/introducing-single-sign-on-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-application/) а так тема весьма обширная.

Comment: где можно пример найти на асп нете?

Comment: для корпоративных приложений есть очень простое решение - вход через AAD (выбрать тип авторизации - organizational accounts). при поддержке sso пароль вводить вообще нужно один раз при включении компьютера.